# Adding missing rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.

```
user cat  val
u1   cat1 1
u1   cat2 2
u1   cat3 3
u2   cat1 5
u3   cat4 4
```

And wish to transform it like this.

```
user cat  val(avg)
u1   cat1 1
u1   cat2 2
u1   cat3 3
u1   cat4 4
u2   cat1 5
u2   cat2 2
u2   cat3 3
u2   cat4 4
u3   cat1 3
u3   cat2 2
u3   cat3 3
u3   cat4 4
```

There are also a couple of numeric columns to the right of cat, which hopefully can be filled with either NA; or if possible averaged out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "averaged out", with an example?

Comment: Edited with example. the val column is the original value, otherwise the average of existing values.

Comment: How you calculated the avg in your example?

Answer (score 5):

one way to solve this,

```
l1=df['user'].unique().tolist()
l2=df['cat'].unique().tolist()
new_df =  pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(l1,l2))).rename(columns={0:'user',1:'cat'})
new_df=pd.merge(new_df,df,on=['user','cat'],how='left')
```

Output:

```
   user   cat  val
0    u1  cat1  1.0
1    u1  cat2  2.0
2    u1  cat3  3.0
3    u1  cat4  NaN
4    u2  cat1  5.0
5    u2  cat2  NaN
6    u2  cat3  NaN
7    u2  cat4  NaN
8    u3  cat1  NaN
9    u3  cat2  NaN
10   u3  cat3  NaN
11   u3  cat4  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to basically reindex your `DataFrame`.

```
from itertools import product

idx = list(product(df['user'].unique(), df['cat'].unique()))
df  = df.set_index(['user', 'cat']).reindex(idx).reset_index()
```

The second part seems to be setting the missing values (in this case `NaN` after the reindex) to the average value from that category. You can accomplish this with a mapping and `groupby` to calculate the average.

```
df.loc[df.val.isnull(), 'val'] = df.loc[df.val.isnull(), 'cat'].map(df.groupby('cat').val.mean())
```

`df` is now:

```
   user   cat  val
0    u1  cat1  1.0
1    u1  cat2  2.0
2    u1  cat3  3.0
3    u1  cat4  4.0
4    u2  cat1  5.0
5    u2  cat2  2.0
6    u2  cat3  3.0
7    u2  cat4  4.0
8    u3  cat1  3.0
9    u3  cat2  2.0
10   u3  cat3  3.0
11   u3  cat4  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) to expose the missing values :

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

df.complete('user', 'cat')
   user   cat  val
0    u1  cat1  1.0
1    u1  cat2  2.0
2    u1  cat3  3.0
3    u1  cat4  NaN
4    u2  cat1  5.0
5    u2  cat2  NaN
6    u2  cat3  NaN
7    u2  cat4  NaN
8    u3  cat1  NaN
9    u3  cat2  NaN
10   u3  cat3  NaN
11   u3  cat4  4.0
```

Comment: its very handy to use `complete`. I think pandas developers should add that in the main library itself.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma maybe you can raise a request for it? possibly make a PR?

Comment: I guess we could raise a PR, not sure if they will accept it but nevertheless that's a good idea. Let's do it together :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a cross join between the unique values of each column

You can do this creating two dataframes with unique values from each

```
df_col1 = pd.DataFrame(df['user'].unique(), columns=['user'])
df_col2 = pd.DataFrame(df['cat'].unique(), columns=['cat'])

# This step will make a dummy var in each dataframe which will be used to 
# merge the dataframes
merged = df_col1.assign(key=1).merge(df_col2.assign(key=1)).drop(['key'], 1)
```